# Solution of the recurrence relation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

It can be proved by induction that the recurrence relation $$K_n(u,v)=\int_0^1K_1(u,u_1)K_{n-1}(u_1,v)du_1,$$ with $K_1(u,v)=\theta(1-u-v)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function with $\theta(0)=1/2$, has the solution (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2055 )
$$K_{2n}(u,v)=(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n-2}}{(2n-1)!}\left ( \left [  E_{2n-1}\left (
\frac{u+v}{2}\right )+E_{2n-1}\left (\frac{u-v}{2}\right )\right ]\theta(u-v)+\right . $$
$$\left . \left [  E_{2n-1}\left (\frac{u+v}{2}\right )+
E_{2n-1}\left (\frac{v-u}{2}\right )\right ]\theta(v-u) \right )$$
and
$$K_{2n+1}(u,v)=(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}\left ( \left [  E_{2n}\left (
\frac{1-u+v}{2}\right )+E_{2n}\left (\frac{1-u-v}{2}\right )\right ]\theta(1-u-v)+\right . $$
$$\left . \left [  E_{2n}\left (\frac{1-u+v}{2}\right )-
E_{2n}\left (\frac{u+v-1}{2}\right )\right ]\theta(u+v-1)\right ) .$$
In these formulas $E_n(x)$ are the Euler polynomials.

These expressions have been simply guessed. How can these results be obtained 
by some systematic method?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The question is how this solution can be obtained by some regular method without guessing it (which was not a simple task).